# Azure - Enable notifications for ACR Tasks

Tags: azure

We have a Container Registry on Azure with  ACR Tasks. Sometimes, a task fail for different reasons and I would like to be notified so I can take appropriate actions (email for instance). What would be the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as I know there is no feature to notify you that the ACR tasks have been implemented. Maybe you can monitor the service health and set the notification, but it does not support monitoring the ACR task.